# Is the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation outdated?

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

Many (if not all) MSDN pages documenting the Microsoft Enterprise Library Validation Block start with a warning:

> This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained. It is provided as a courtesy for individuals who are still using these technologies. This page may contain URLs that were valid when originally published, but now link to sites or pages that no longer exist.

see for example [Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation Namespace page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.validation.aspx). Is this block outdated? or the whole Microsoft Enterprise Library Block is deprecated?

Comment: Yes, according to MSDN it is. And they say you should reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc467894.aspx now.

Comment: And you have that link right below the paragraph you quoted, in the page you linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise Library is not deprecated and the Validation Application Block still exists in the latest version (version 6).  You can read about it in [Chapter 7 of the Developer's Guide, Banishing Validation Complication: Using the Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440720(v=pandp.60).aspx).

The reason for the "outdated" message is that the documentation for previous versions ("Retired Releases") is left up on MSDN.

Before using the Validation Application Block for a new project, I would recommend determining if you need the functionality it provides.  For example, you can use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` with ASP.NET MVC to perform validation without Enterprise Library.